# How to fix a long Time to Interactive in google pagespeed : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, optimization, pagespeed

Can anyone help me to fix

> " Time to Interactive "

In magento 2?

I really hope anyone can help me or tell me how to fix it

Bad score on google pagespeed - 38 sec